# Calendar cuts when i open it in a modal popup

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am facing an issue when I open a bootstrap datepicker in a modal pop-up it cuts off. Please have a look and provide me some suggestion or solutions if available.

```
<input id="doohMediaStartDate" name="startDate" class="form-control input-sm" 
autocomplete="off" ng-model="slot.startDate" placeholder="Start Date" />
```

[image]

Comment: add the html and css page code

Comment: please share example code

Comment: add `z-index` to the datepicker

Comment: please provide a code sample.If you can put those code sample in Codepen and share the URL

Comment: I tried z-index but no luck.

Comment: @Ahetesham This is not a z-index issue.Provide a code samples

Answer (score 0):

Inspect element and find the div of the datepicker object/popup.
You can then attempt to move that object by: *height of booking date input* + *height of datepicker object itself*. Say the calculation above gives you a size of `300px`. Thus, you can apply a `margin-top: 300px` to the datepicker object to move it below the input.

Therefore, the user will still be able to see what field they are populating, although some of the fields below will be covered. Likely, this will not be an issue, as the user is currently interacting with that element.